# Optimal Hedging Ratio using Copula Models

Tags: futures, hedging, garch, copula, optimal-hedge-ratio

Let $r_{s, t}$ and $r_{f, t}$ be the return rates of the spot and futures of a commodity at time $t$. The hedging ratio based on variance minimization is calculated by finding the minimum of the variance of the combined returns:

$$\beta_t = \rho_{sf, t} \frac{\sigma_{s, t}}{\sigma_{f, t}},$$

where $\rho_{sf, t}$ is the time-varying correlation and $\sigma_{s, t}$ and $\sigma_{f, t}$ are the corresponding time-varying volatility of the spot and future returns respectively. From the several papers that I went through, the volatility measures are calculated using different GARCH-type models and the filtered standardized residuals are used to estimate various Copula models. My question is how the estimated static Copula models are then transformed to the time-varying correlation that is later used to calculate the hedge ratio? I would really be thankful for any kind of guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a static copula model implies $\rho_{s,f,t}\equiv\rho_{s,f}$. In such case fitting a copula model to obtain $\rho_{s,f}$ is an overkill, since it can be estimated very simply by the empirical correlation of the two standardized residual series from the two GARCH models. Of course, a availability of the joint distribution via a copula-GARCH model facilitates all kinds of interesting calculations, so the model may well be worth fitting, just not for estimating $\rho_{s,f}$ alone.

If you want time-varying correlation, you may be tempted to consider using BEKK-GARCH or DCC-GARCH models; this is what many authors do. However, the models seem to be seriously flawed – **except** for the case of diagonal BEKK-GARCH; see [Caporin & McAleer (2013)](https://www.mdpi.com/2225-1146/1/1/115), [McAleer (2019a)](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/61), [McAleer (2019b)](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/66), [Allen & McAleer (2018)](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/11/7/1627). Other alternatives are time-varying copula GARCH and GO-GARCH, among other, though I am not sure how sound they are theoretically. In any case, the latter two as well as DCC-GARCH are available in the [`rmgarch`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/index.html) package in R should you decide to try them out.

**References:**

- Allen, D. E., & McAleer, M. (2018). [Theoretical and empirical differences between diagonal and full BEKK for risk management](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/11/7/1627). *Energies, 11*(7), 1627.
- Caporin, M., & McAleer, M. (2013). [Ten things you should know about the dynamic conditional correlation representation](https://www.mdpi.com/2225-1146/1/1/115). *Econometrics, 1*(1), 115-126.
- McAleer, M. (2019). [What they did not tell you about algebraic (non-) existence, mathematical (ir-) regularity, and (non-) asymptotic properties of the dynamic conditional correlation (DCC) model](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/61). *Journal of Risk and Financial Management, 12*(2), 61.
- McAleer, M. (2019). [What they did not tell you about algebraic (non-) existence, mathematical (ir-) regularity and (non-) asymptotic properties of the full BEKK dynamic conditional covariance model](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/66). *Journal of Risk and Financial Management, 12*(2), 66.